# How to fix 'RuntimeError: Coordinator stopped with threads still running: QueueRunnerThread-dummy_queue-sync_token_q_EnqueueMany'

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm new to TensorFlow and every time I trained my model, it ends with the error :

```
RuntimeError: Coordinator stopped with threads still running: QueueRunnerThread-dummy_queue-sync_token_q_EnqueueMany
```

Does someone have any idea to fix it ?

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and using Python3.6 and TensorFlow 1.12.0 version, and using the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor` as model. To train it, I used the `legacy/train.py` script.

I've try to look at GitHub issues, but I don't understand many things.
This error comes from : `/home/ant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py`

It happens just after TensorFlow save the checkpoint

## Here are logs when it crashes:

```py
INFO:tensorflow:Stopping Training.
I0412 11:09:09.962124 139983862277952 tf_logging.py:115] Stopping Training.
INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
I0412 11:09:09.962288 139983862277952 tf_logging.py:115] Finished training! Saving model to disk.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 184, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/ant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/ant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 306, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "object_detection/train.py", line 180, in main
    graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py", line 415, in train
    saver=saver)
  File "/home/ant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 785, in train
    ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/home/ant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 832, in stop
    ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/home/ant/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 397, in join
    " ".join(stragglers))
RuntimeError: Coordinator stopped with threads still running: QueueRunnerThread-dummy_queue-sync_token_q_EnqueueMany
```

Comment: Well, it seems I've temporarily fix it:
I just deleted the line NUM_STEPS: in my pipeline config file.

It now save me a checkpoint every 25 steps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem，my tf version is 1.13，then I upgraded to version 1.14，there's also a same error.

Finally, I change `ignore_liver_threads=False` to `ignore_liver_threads=True` in both `../tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py` and `../tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py`.